# Toggle on click except one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, toggle

Given the following html structure, how to make `#top-bar-toggle` toggle on click except when clicking `.top-bar-menu-search` or its children?

```html
<div id="top-bar-toggle">
    <div id="top-bar-menu">
        <ul class="vertical menu">
            <li>
                <a href="home_link"><h2>Home Item</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="other_link"><h2>Other Item</h2></a>
                <ul class="nested vertical menu">
                    <li><a href="nested_link"><h2>Nested Item</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="nested_link"><h2>Nested Item</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="nested_link"><h2>Nested Item</h2></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="other_link"><h2>Other Item</h2></a>
                <ul class="nested vertical menu">
                    <li><a href="nested_link"><h2>Nested Item</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="nested_link"><h2>Nested Item</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="nested_link"><h2>Nested Item</h2></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="top-bar-menu-search">
                <form id="searchform" method="get" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-label"></span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="s" name="s" value="" class="input-group-field">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought the following jquery code would work, but the `#top-bar-toggle` element gets toggled anyway…

```js
$('#top-bar-toggle').not('.top-bar-menu-search').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeToggle();
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use stopPropagation method of jquery.

```
$('#top-bar-toggle').click(function() {
    console.log("topbar clicked");
  });
  $('.top-bar-menu-search').click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("searchbar clicked");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give all elements class "A" for example then on onclick of class A check if the id of element is not excepted id toggle it...
$(".A").on("click",function(){

if($(this).attr("id")!="B")
   $(this).fadeToggle()

})

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will help you

```
$('#top-bar-menu>ul>li>a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();

});
```

Comment: It just didn't work because I need the `#top-bar-toggle` element to toggle when one also clicks outside the `#top-bar-menu`. But thank you anyway for your answer.